# Is there a way to trigger mouseup when leaving the document body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mouseup

I found some code and I made a [jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/vp14utt1/) with it. I need to know how to trigger mouseup in the function below, when you leave document body (in the fiddle example it's like dragging the object into HTML section for instance and leave the mouse click there).

```
function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (canMove) {
        var left = getMousePosX(e);
        var top = getMousePosY(e);
        var newLeft = ($(elemToMove).css('left').toDecNum() + (left - lastPosX));
        var newTop = ($(elemToMove).css('top').toDecNum() + (top - lastPosY));

        $(elemToMove).css('left', newLeft);
        $(elemToMove).css('top', newTop);
        lastPosX = left;
        lastPosY = top;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: elem to move would leave the boundries of doc, so you want to check for those cases.  if it is true, then.... trigger("mouseup");   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
document.onmouseout = handleMouseUp;
```

This says that when the mouse leaves the document object, the `handleMouseUp` handler should be called.

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vp14utt1/1/

-

P.S. for event handlers that simply take the event as an argument, you can just use the function name without wrapping it.

```
document.onmousedown = function (e) { handleMouseDown(e); };
document.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume `mouseout` is a perfect replacement or emulation for `touchcancel`, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with touch events but I would not make that assumption.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel suggests that `touchcancel` is implementation specific and has less to do with leaving a particular element/window than the user invalidating a touch event.  `touchend` might be of interest to you but I can't really elaborate any more than a quick Google search.

Comment: I've finished the code, I forked the code into 2 separate handler sets, one for touch enabled displays, and one for clickers. As to my understanding, Microsoft unifies both with their pointer events, who cares, I managed my code and THANKS again for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elemToMove).trigger('mouseup');
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line ([new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p9o249f/1/)):

```
document.onmouseleave = function (e) { handleMouseUp(e); };
```

This fires your 'mouse up' logic when the mouse is dragged off the browser window.

To quote [The difference between mouseout() and mouseleave()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout):

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child elements as well the selected element.
>
> The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves the selected element.

I think you want the later.